# Problem with assigning an array to other array in Java

Tags: java, arrays

```
public class TestingArray {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int iCheck = 10;
        int j = iCheck;
        j = 11;
        System.err.println("value of iCheck "+iCheck);

        int[] val1 = {1,2,9,4,5,6,7};
        int[] val2 = val1;
        val2[0] = 200;
        System.err.println("Array Value "+val1[0]);
    }
}
```

Output:

> **value of iCheck 10
>
>   Array Value 200**

From the above code, I found that if any array `val2` is being assigned to another array `val1` and if we change any value of `val2` array, the result is as well reflected for the array `val1` while the same scenario is not with variable assignment.
Why?

Answer (score 39, accepted):

The following statement makes `val2` refer to the same array as `val1`:

```
int[] val2 = val1;
```

If you want to make a copy, you could use `val1.clone()` or [`Arrays.copyOf()`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#copyOf%28int%5B%5D,%20int%29):

```
int[] val2 = Arrays.copyOf(val1, val1.length);
```

Objects (including instances of collection classes, `String`, `Integer` etc) work in a similar manner, in that assigning one variable to another simply copies the reference, making both variables refer to the same object. If the object in question is mutable, then subsequent modifications made to its contents via one of the variables will also be visible through the other.

Primitive types (`int`, `double` etc) behave differently: there are no references involved and assignment makes a copy of the value.

Answer (score 4):

Simply put, "val1" and "val2" are pointers to the actual array.  You're assigning val2 to point to the same array as val1.  Therefore, change one, and the other sees the same change.  To have it truly be a copy, you'd have to clone the array instead of assigning.

Answer (score 4):

Because arrays in Java are objects, i.e. passed by reference.

Answer (score 1):

Because you assign a reference of `val1` to `val2`, so they both point to the same object in the memory.