# Array returning null

Tags: java, arrays, csv, file, null

I'm trying to read into a csv file and placing the line into an array. But when I print the array out it is null.

Here is the code:

```
public static String[] readFile(String inFilename)
{
    int lineTotal = getLineNum(inFilename); 
    if (lineTotal == 0)
    {
        System.out.println("The file is empty ");
    }
    FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr; 
    String[] resultArrayOne = new String[lineTotal + 1];
    String line;
    try 
    { 
        fileStrm = new FileInputStream(inFilename); //open file
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm); //create a reader to read the stream
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);//read file line by line 
        int lineNum;
        String[] resultArray = new String[lineTotal];
        String info;

        lineNum = 0;
        while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null)  //While not end-of-file, process and read lines
        {
            info = line; 
            System.out.println(info);
            resultArray[lineNum] = info;
            lineNum++; 
        }
        fileStrm.close(); //Clean up the stream
        resultArrayOne = resultArray; 
    }
    catch (IOException e) // MUST catch IOExceptions
    {
        if (fileStrm != null)  //Clean up the stream if it was opened
        {
            try 
            { 
                fileStrm.close(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException ex2) { } // We can’t do anything more!
        }
        System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage()); //Or do a throw
    }
    return resultArrayOne;  
}
```

When printing out the line before placing it into the array the return is fine, but when placed into the array it become null.

edit:

Here is the full FileIO code:

```
public static String[] Import()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Please enter the File Name: ");
    String fileName = sc.nextLine();
    int length = getLineNum(fileName); 
    String[] array = new String[length+1];
    array = readFile(fileName); 
    return array; //array is just strings     
}

public static int getLineNum(String inFilename)
{
    FileInputStream fileStrm = null;
    InputStreamReader rdr;
    BufferedReader bufRdr; 
    String line;
    int lineNum = 0; 
    try 
    { 
        fileStrm = new FileInputStream(inFilename); //open file
        rdr = new InputStreamReader(fileStrm); //create a reader to read the stream
        bufRdr = new BufferedReader(rdr);//read file line by line 
        lineNum = 0;
        while ((line = bufRdr.readLine()) != null)  //While not end-of-file, process and read lines
        {
            lineNum++; 
        }
        fileStrm.close(); //Clean up the stream
    }
    catch (IOException e) // MUST catch IOExceptions
    {
        if (fileStrm != null)  //Clean up the stream if it was opened
        {
            try 
            { 
                fileStrm.close(); 
            } 
            catch (IOException ex2) { } // We can’t do anything more!
        }
        System.out.println("Error in file processing: " + e.getMessage()); //Or do a throw
    }
    return lineNum;  
}
```

I'm not too sure how to insert a sample file but it is something like this:

```
SHOP1, STORE2, 45
SHOP2, SHOP1, 67
STORE6, SHOP1, 90
...
```

edit 2:

I added the code that uses this

```
String[] locationArrayOne = new String[1000];     
locationArrayOne = FileIO.Import();
                                    for (int yyy = 0; yyy < locationArrayOne.length; yyy++)
                                    {
                                        System.out.print(locationArray[yyy]);  
                                    }
```

Comment: If I were to place a for loop at the end of the class before the return statement looping through the array and returning each String, the out print is null.

Comment: If all you want is to load the contents of the CSV file into an array where each array element is a line from the file, why not just call method [readLines](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/nio/file/Files.html#readAllLines-java.nio.file.Path-) in class `java.nio.files.Files`. It returns a `List` which you can convert to an array via method [toArray](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/List.html#toArray-T:A-) (in interface `java.util.List`).

Answer (score 1):

Your code looks fine but here is how I would debug the problem:

1. Before `lineNum++`, I will print the value of `resultArray[lineNum]` instead of `info` to see if the program was able to retrieve the line and store it to the array.
2. Remove the initialization of `String[] resultArrayOne` and after `fileStrm.close()`, use `resultArrayOne = resultArray.clone()` to copy the values of `resultArray` to `resultArrayOne`. Copying an array by assignment (array1 = array2) could have side-effects you do not want in your program since you are making both arrays refer to the same object. [Check this related question here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7350173/problem-with-assigning-an-array-to-other-array-in-java)

Also, why not use `resultArrayOne` directly when storing the lines?